# Sideway Content overflow in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following situation, there is a div and I am dynamically adding content to it. As of now if the content added is too much it overflows outside the div or elongates the div. 
Both these situations are undesirable to me.

[image]

What I want to do is to overflow the content on the side, in a separate column.
I using bootstrap fluid columns for this, but even a solution which doesn't depend on bootsrap will do good to me.

My last option is to encapsulate the code in a bunch of if and else and put content in the two columns accordingly, but I think there might be a simpler solution to this problem.

Thanks

here is the jsfiddle as requested http://jsfiddle.net/eak4e/1/

```
some compulsory code
```

Comment: can provide a fiddle for that ??

Comment: I have updated my question with the fiddle @CodingAnt

Comment: @Tomarinator, so you will have fixed height, actually?

Comment: @nevermind yes so that I have fixed height if the content added is more than the current height it overflows in the next column.

Comment: You could be interessted in using columns. here is a little fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wkr7X/

Comment: @NicoO, great, post it as solution, so other people can see it easily. :)

Comment: ok i posted it as answer. But i have not too much experience using columns. Maybe someone with more insight (using it with block elements etc.) will update the answer and make it therefore more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution (IE10+) are CSS columns. here is a little fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wkr7X/

```
div.text-columns-three
{
 /*Shamless copy of: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/columns/*/
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -ms-column-count: 3;
  -o-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

    height: 300px;
}
```

There are some interesting properties like  `column-break-inside`

Update: here is a short experiment with different display types: http://jsfiddle.net/wkr7X/1/ seems to work with block elements, as long as the content is not one block but splited in several entities